# Flutter Text Widget Emojis

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting back JSON Data from my server but emojis are being serialized with weird characters.

```
msgcontent: â¤ï¸â¤ï¸â¤ï¸ð,
```

I'm using the http package. On postman it shows the emoji perfectly so it's not a db or json error. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid Arabic characters With Utf-8 charset Retrived with http.get Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50318681/invalid-arabic-characters-with-utf-8-charset-retrived-with-http-get-flutter)

Comment: @RichardHeap it's similar to what I was looking for but the wrong answer. Check below for the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

Answering my own question after doing some research this is the best and simplest way without using a Future. You can put this anywhere.

```
import 'dart:convert';

String utf8convert(String text) {
    List<int> bytes = text.toString().codeUnits;
    return utf8.decode(bytes);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**JUST IN CASE IF SOMEONE IS LOOKING FOR AN EASIER AND CONVENIENT SOLUTION TO THIS VERY PROBLEM**

After seeing Leoog's answer, what I would suggest is instead of having a separate function to perform UTF decoding, you can rather simply edit your network request code from something like

```dart
final response = await http.get(....);
final result = jsonDecode(response.body);
```

to

```
final response = await http.get(....);
final result = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
```

This way the UTF decoding would take place inside the data layer keeping our presentation layer neat thus promoting [separation of concerns](https://medium.com/machine-words/separation-of-concerns-1d735b703a60).

Comment: This is the best solution. Clean and simple, thank you!

Comment: You are most welcome, @Owen

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding/decoding your data with UTF8 character encoding, this might just do the trick, previously answered:

[Flutter UTF8 encoding/decoding answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51101618/10768398)

Answer (score 0):

```
    import 'dart:convert' show utf8;
   Text( utf8.decode(receivedString.runes.toList()) );
```

Try this this should work